# Do_shortcode function does not work outside WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

When I try to run shortcode by this code:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );        
require_once('account/wp-blog-header.php');
require_once('account/wp-includes/shortcodes.php');

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);

get_header();
$page_object = get_page( 28 );
var_dump($page_object);
echo do_shortcode($page_object->post_content);
```

I get page with only header, so do_shortcode didn't work. 
Dump of page_object returns me this:

```
object(WP_Post)[276]
  public 'ID' => int 28
  public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'post_date' => string '2015-09-22 12:14:16' (length=19)
  public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2015-09-22 12:14:16' (length=19)
  public 'post_content' => string '[pmpro_levels]' (length=14)
  public 'post_title' => string 'Membership Levels' (length=17)
  public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
  public 'comment_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
  public 'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
  public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_name' => string 'levels' (length=6)
  public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_modified' => string '2015-09-22 12:14:16' (length=19)
  public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2015-09-22 12:14:16' (length=19)
  public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_parent' => int 22
  public 'guid' => string 'http://phpstack-10604-23437-55300.cloudwaysapps.com/account/membership-account-2/membership-levels/' (length=99)
  public 'menu_order' => int 0
  public 'post_type' => string 'page' (length=4)
  public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

And `$page_object->post_content;` returns me [pmpro_levels], but 
`do_shortcode()` doesn't parse shortcode.
Everything works inside WordPress directory, as you can see upwhere I call wp-blog-header.php, but it didn't work.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

you should try apply_filter

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

apply_filters('the_content', $content); is used to apply the content filters to raw unfiltered post content, which usually comes from the use of $post->post_content. These filters include the famous filter wp_autop which adds p tags to the_content()

apply_filters('the_content', $content); is usally used in conjuction with get_posts where one works directly with the WP_Post objects without using setup_postdata( $post ) which makes the template tags like the_content() available for use

Update -
This is how your code should be

```
get_header();
$page_object = get_page( 28 );
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_object->post_content);
```

Comment: Why OP should try it? Explain, please (inside the answer).

Comment: Thank you for reply.

When i try this

$content = get_the_content();
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
 var_dump($content);

I get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/31175-23437.cloudwaysapps.com/zzazfhvsnt/public_html/account/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 279

Comment: @LahiruNanayakkara Nope, result of echo is just: [pmpro_levels] . :/
What 'the_content' means?